# WebViewClient with file Chooser

Tags: android, webview, filechooser

I am currently working on an app which includes 2 webViews but there is a Problem:

Both WebViews are "Extended" WebViews which use the Android Standard WebViewClient.

Both pages are asking the user to select a photo, but when I use this WebViewClient, the file chooser doesn't open.

How must my WebViewClient be so that every http:// and https:// is charged in the WebView and not in the external browser and file choosing requests can be handled by Gallery, File Explorer etc.??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using KitKat, this is a [documented](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220) [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5294).

Comment: I have found that FileChooser works with pre KitKat devices, but not on 4.4+. Last time I checked, it still worked with JellyBean. If you can't see it in JellyBean either, maybe your problem is a different one. Try posting your code.

Comment: Thanks, but if it doesn't work on KitKat, I won't include it. The Feature should also be available on the newest System. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. As you can see in the links I posted, there's a strong debate over at the Google Code forums. Let's hope they include it back in the future.